# Overload assignment operator C++ passing non-const parameter

Tags: c++, queue

I'm building my own data structures in C++ for university and I've a problem with "queue" data structure.
In particular when I'm trying to overload the assignment operator like this:

```
Queue& operator=(Queue& C){

   if(this != &C){
     elements = new element_type[C.maxlength];
     maxlength = C.maxlength;
     length = C.length;
     head = C.head;

     if(!C.emptyQueue()){
       for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
         pushQueue(C.readQueue());
       }
       C.pushQueue(C.readQueue());
       C.popQueue();
     }
   }
   return *this;
}
```

the complier says 
"cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Queue&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Queue’"
But, from the moment I need to modify the input parameter (cause to read every value from the queue and push it into the new queue, I need to pop every element) I think it's mandatory to pass it without const. 
Is there another way to do this or I'm missing something?

Comment: What assignment is this supposed to be? If you're modifying the original queue, essentially taking all items out of it, it should be a move-assignment, which it isn't.

Comment: Here is something to think about. Generally, when we write `a = b`, we don't expect `b` to change as a result. Your code, as written, breaks that expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy assignment operator is actually a move, not a copy assignment.

Use the move assignment:

```
Queue& operator=(Queue&& C){
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I see that using you solution is working great. So what's the difference between a move and assignment? I mean, in the main.cpp I am doing an assignment between two queues, so why can't I call it assignment?

Comment: As other comments said, it's not an assignment if you are changing the original object `b`, it's a move if you transfer data from `b` to `a`.

Comment: Its neither move nor assignment, its 'move assignment'. The alternative would be 'copy assignment'.